# How to center a ul menu?

Tags: css

I have this ul menu:

```
<ul id="superfish-1">
  <li class="active-trail"><a href="#" class="sf-depth-1  active">Inicio</a></li>
  <li class="trail"><a href="#" class="sf-depth-1">Quienes somos</a></li>
  <li class="trail"><a href="#" class="sf-depth-1">Contacto</a></li>

</ul>
```

and I need to align it horizontally.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865380/how-do-i-center-align-horizontal-ul-menu) but positioning the ul as `postion:relative;` and setting `left:50%` didn't make it.

I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436524/css-wont-center-the-ul-li-horizontal-menu) but in my case I can't set the width manually because the menu load its content dinamically, then the width changes all the time.

This is what I need: [image: capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write like this:

```
    #superfish-1{
     text-align:center;
    }
    li{
     display:inline-block;
     *display:inline;/*For IE7*/
     *zoom:1;/*For IE7*/
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/SdkKd/

Comment: I can't set width with a fixed value. The width of the menu change when the site is loaded in other languages, then this won't work.

Comment: i see, it works in your link, but not in my site. I'll check the inherited styles it might have.

Comment: This way should work. However, it's the li elements that center, not the ul, if that's your problem.

Comment: I spotted the problem, my li element has the style `float:left;` which is why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0 auto;` to css of ul.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dURBJ/1/

Comment: but as he said it's a dynamic width

Comment: if I add margin:0 auto; I need to add the width with a fixed value. The width of the menu change when the site is loaded in other languages, then this won't work.