# Center the li and the margin of the last child

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to center a ul and the li inside. I think the problem is the left margin of the last li. I tried two things but it does not seems to affect. What is the problem ?

CSS:

```
ul {
    position:relative;
    width: 640px;
    margin:40px auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: verdana; 
    font-size:10px;
    color: #666
}

ul li:last-child { margin-right: 0px; }
/* ul li.last-item { margin-right: 0px; } */
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li> first </li>
  <li> second </li>
  <li> third </li>
  <li> fourth </li>
  <li> fifth </li>
  <li> sixth </li>
</ul>
```

I have it here life: http://jsfiddle.net/a4aQN/

Comment: Shouldn't the ul be 650px wide: 5x110 + 1x100?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11033022/1313143

Comment: You are write. Sorry, my mistake !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the proper CSS to do that:

```
ul {
    margin: 40px auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    color: #666
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4aQN/1/)

Essentially I put `text-align: center;` on your `ul`. You had some other things too that you didn't need, such as settings its width and the `float: left;` on your `li`s.

Comment: This is really good! Thank you. In your case the last child is not needed?

Comment: In the left side it appears a margin that makes it not totally centered. I dont' understand why?. It does not appear in Fiddle but it appears in a normal html and in JBin : http://jsbin.com/icomin/1/ and CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jexAG

Comment: I think your solution is really good but it needs to add the padding 0 in the ul and ul li:last-child { margin-right: 0px; } to be complitely centered: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jexAG